# Getting SQL query from a database

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

We have a postgres database which is connected using typeorm, and unfortunately all development was done using `{synchronize: true}` option in typeorm configuration settings leaving us with no migration. Now writing migration for each one of it will be a heavy task.

I was curious if we can get the SQL query for creating the db with existing tables and columns??

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to dump the entire database and then import it.

Comment: How do we do that?

Comment: You can use `pg_dump databaseName > outputFile` to dump the file 

and then `psql empty_database < outputFile` to restore it

You can find more information [here](https://www.educba.com/postgres-dump-database/)

Answer (score 0):

With typeorm you can do:

```
npx typeorm migration:generate -n InitialMigration
```

see [enter link description here](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/migrations#generating-migrations)

P.s. if it doesn't create the table query because they are already in the DB, drop everything from Database and run the command. Or run the migration command pointing to an empty database.

P.p.s.
If the command is not found with **npx**, you can try

```
./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate ...
```